# How can I move a matrix in excel one column to the right and input strings?

Tags: python, excel, matrix, move

I was wondering how I can move a matrix in excel one column to the right and input on that vacant column a series of strings such as "dog" going down all rows and "Target" on the top most row and leftmost column?

From the image link attached below outlining what I want to program for:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrmqZ.png)

Sample program below outlining what I currently am coding:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
main=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/testfile/testing.csv', header=None)
```

Thanks.
New error image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPJsO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .insert() with loc = 0. It seems in your example data image that the first row is column names? In that case remove header = None when you read csv:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

main=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/testfile/testing.csv')

target_col = ['dog'] * main.shape[0]
main.insert(loc = 0, column = 'target', value = target_col)
```

Comment: Hi @Anynamer, I am getting an error reading ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index, when it should be right?. How can I do this automatically for large datasets with thousands of rows without manual input?

Comment: Hi I made a small edit, you use header = None when you read csv, but in your image it looks like first row is the header?

Comment: So your error sounds like the length of your new column values is different from the dataframe row length. I just made the mockup with ['dog', 'dog', 'dog'], the column values should match your real dataframe size. It depends on what value you want in your 'target' column. Same value all the way makes little sense, but if want you can do : target_col = ['dog'] * main.shape[0]

Comment: I'm using no headers so I can attach "Target" next to the 800, 1000, 1200, 1400 columns. Thanks for re-editing the program that line of code does the macro correctly but "Dog" is along the 800,1200,1400 columns. I've re-edited my post to attach a link to another image which shows this. Thanks

Comment: If you want 800, 1000, 1200, 1400  to be column names and not values, then you should not use header = None.  The main.insert can then add 'target' as a new column name "next to" 800, 1000, 1200, 1400.  Your new error shows exactly what happens, you have used header=none and pandas has made new indeces for column names, and when you insert the 'target' column, it adds the column name next to those created indeces. So try without header = none and all should be good :)